# AEM Target third party id to set on profile

Tags: reactjs, aem

I am trying to set `mbox3rdPartyID` using Adobe Target AEM module in my ReactJS web app. I am using the following code in ReactJS app. But, when i launch this page, it doesn't get `mbox3rdPartyID`. I am checking this ID through [MiaProva - Chrome plugin](https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fmiaprova%2Fmgmachpoeeklnmmiamheacganlehicdb)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {hot} from 'react-hot-loader';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let event = new CustomEvent('at-start', {
            detail: {
                mbox: 'target-global-mbox',
                params: {                        
                    mbox3rdPartyID: '123123123'
                }
            }
        });
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Template title="My Test Adobe App">
                <Helmet
                    title="New Web Ref App"
                    script={[
                        {
                            innerHTML:
                                'document.addEventListener("at-start", function(event) { var mbox = event.detail.mbox; var params = event.detail.params; adobe.target.getOffer({ mbox: mbox, params: params, success: function(offers) { var e = new CustomEvent("at-offers-received", {detail: {offers : offers, mbox: mbox } }); document.dispatchEvent(e); },error: function(status, error) {console.warn("Adobe Target custom mBox ( " + mbox + " ) request did not succeed :: ", status, error); var e = new CustomEvent("at-offers-received", {detail: {offers : [], mbox: mbox}}); document.dispatchEvent(e);} });});'
                        },
                        {
                            innerHTML: 'window.targetGlobalSettings = {globalMboxAutoCreate: false}'
                        },
                        {
                            src: 'https://xxxxx/at.js',
                            type: 'text/javascript'
                        }
                    ]}
                />
            </Template>
        );
    }
}
export default hot(module)(App);
```

Could someone please help me to know what is wrong in it?

Comment: Is there a error in dev console? Are you looking for value to be available in `render` method?

Comment: I am not getting any error in dev console Sandeep. I've published my web page in dev/test environment and testing it. I want to know, 1.) Is my code correct to send mbox3rdPartyID? If yes, why doesn't it send it? (2.) whether the way i am trying to see mbox3rdPartyID is correct or not? is there any other way to see it once i run the web app and deployed?

Comment: I am also seeing a warning in dev console like this-> "AT: Rendering mbox failed target-global-mbox Error: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.Ra.a.onerror (tab.js-source?resourceHash=6398df8187f97c89b13e8b5ac098dca97ce76b0d:93894)

Comment: What i understand is you are making Target Offer call via `adobe.target.getOffer` method, this internally makes XHR call to fetch the offer. Is there a trace in callback method. As per [Adobe Target documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/target/ov2/cmp_at.js_Functions.html), status, error is passed to error callback function. Can you print what is the error trace? Also you can try to first execute the mbox call with hardcoded mboxID in dev console if that is succeeding, then other part of passing mbox ID to method needs to be checked.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually i don't want adobe.target.getOffer and all. I just need to pass mbox3rdPartyID. I am not that experienced in ReactsJS code. Need help sending it.

Comment: Only with {
                            src: 'https://xxxxx/at.js',
                            type: 'text/javascript'
                        } I am able to get visitor ID and cloud ID. I think, there is a problem in "innerHTML"

Comment: I just tried, {
                            innerHTML:
                                'document.addEventListener("at-view-start", function(event) { var mbox = event.detail.mbox; var params = event.detail.params; } });});'
                        }, but still not getting "mbox3rdPartyID"

Comment: I think if you notice you are internally using `adobe.target.getOffer` in react code. I guess you are trying to validate the values in chrome plugin for target activity for a particular mbox. I am sorry I am not able to get the complete picture of what you are trying to do. I think you are trying to pass values via custom event object in `componentDidMount` method and `render` method you are injecting Adobe Target library (via React Helmet) to pull offer but that is failing. .